# how to make cmake clion intellisense works with .mqh file

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

I'm trying to make the clion intellisense works with mql language `.mqh` files

it's C++ like language and vscode can parse the code without any cmake file. but clion need a cmakeList.txt to have the intellisense worked.

folder structure looks like below:

[image: mql folder structure]

most of the includes file that are equivelant of `.h` files are in the `include` folder.

the executable could be in any other folder and has `.mq4` extension but that shouldn't be matter since the compiler isn't clang so even both extension be considered as `.h` file is fine

this is my cmake. my goal is only to make the clion intellisence works.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(mqh-cmake)

#set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD C23)

file(GLOB_RECURSE header_files "include/**/*.mqh")
file(GLOB_RECURSE executable_files "**/*.mq4")
foreach(f ${header_files})
    message("processing ${f}")
endforeach()

foreach(f ${executable_files})
    message("processing ${f}")
endforeach()

include_directories(${header_files}
        ${executable_files})

#add_executable(mqh-cmake Scripts/TestGround.mq4)
```

and this cmake parse all the `.mqh` and `.mq4` files

[image]

but still when I go to any `mq4` or `mqh` file, the intellisense doesn't work

[image]

my goal isn't to make the cmake to works, but make clion intellisense works.

the interesting part is that clion out of the box recognize `.mqh` files as c++ files
[image]

but still the intellisence doesn't work

Comment: I don't see MQL on the supported languages for clion https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/features/supported-languages.html you will likely need a plugin

Comment: it's C equivalent. please check last image. already it's part of the c++ extensions. also it's not worthy of a big title at the webpage

Comment: Seems you need to add `executable_files` and `header_files` to any target (as you do it for `TestGround.mq4`). CLion will know about the compilation switches to start indexing the sources for navigation.